# Upload files to amazon aws3 rails with carrierwave error hostname does not match the server certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I followed this tutorial:
http://lifesforlearning.com/uploading-images-with-carrierwave-to-s3-on-rails/
I had working carrierwave uploader which was storing files to disk space
What I did step by step:
1)added `fog` gem and run `bundle install` and `bundle update`

2)in config/initializers  I created r3.rb file with this:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

      config.fog_credentials = {
          :provider               => 'AWS',
          :aws_access_key_id      => 'mykey',
          :aws_secret_access_key  => 'mysecretkey',
          :region                 => 'us-west-2' # Change this for different AWS region. 
      }
      config.fog_directory  = "bucket-main"
    end
```

I ran rails s and tried to save some photo. But as you can see on the picture my bucket is empty.So they must be stored to my disk.
What do I do now?

[image]

Update I changed storage to fog.

Here is my photouploader class code:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base


  storage :fog
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

And now I get this error:

> hostname "bucket-main.bucket-main.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com" does not
>   match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Answer (score 2):

i eventually solved my problem by updating
`bundle update fog`
and 
`bundle update carrierwave`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `path_style` to your config and the `fog_directory`

```
config.fog_credentials = {
    ...
   :path_style => true
}
config.fog_directory = 'bucket-main'
```

Comment: try just path_style true and forget the fog_directory

Comment: `is not a recognized provider` - the same error. Any  ideas?

Comment: can you also see this question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511712/set-secret-keys-for-amazon-aws3

Answer (score 0):

I just spent a few hours tracking down the cause of this error, which I was also getting:

> hostname "bucket-main.bucket-main.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

The odd thing is how the bucket name is repeated twice in the hostname. It turned out I had configured the wrong region name. Notice in your `config.fog_credentials` you have

> `:region                 => 'us-west-2'`

...but the hostname in the exception has `s3-us-west-1`? If your bucket is in one AWS region, but you configure a different region in your Fog credentials, Fog will try to follow a redirect from AWS, and somehow the bucket name gets doubled up in this situation. Fog produces a warning about the redirect, but Carrierwave ends up hiding this from you.

Set `:region` in your Fog credentials to where the bucket actually is in AWS, and the `does not match the server certificate` exception will stop happening.