# set secret keys for amazon aws3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3

I use fog and carrierwave. Right now I just have simple uploader that I run locally:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
        :provider               => 'AWS',
        :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['S3_ACCESS_KEY'],
        :aws_secret_access_key  =>  ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region                 => 'us-west-1', # Change this for 

  }
  config.fog_directory  = "bucket-main"    
end
```

But now I have a question where should I save my secret keys.

On heroku environment I could print like this

```
$ heroku config:set S3_ACCESS_KEY=THERANDOMKEYYOUGOT  
$ heroku config:set S3_SECRET_KEY=an0tHeRstRing0frAnDomjUnK  
$ heroku config:set S3_REGION=us-west-2  
$ heroku config:set S3_BUCKET=my-sample-app-bucket-20160126
```

But I don't know what to do on my local machine.

I've followed this tutorial https://github.com/sifxtreme/rails-carrierwave-s3

And stored my keys in `config/secrets.yml file` which I just created:

```
development: &defaults
  S3_ACCESS_KEY: "AKHJJHHJHJJHHJHJDHJDDJDHJDHJDJHDRANDOMFQ"
  S3_SECRET_KEY: "HfkdjgjkfjkgjkfjkRANDOM2JSJDKKJJKSSJDJKSKaN"

test:
  <<: *defaults

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  <<: *defaults
```

> But rails s command gives me this error:
>   /home/jonstark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/fog-core-1.35.0/lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in
>   `validate_options': Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id,
>   aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)

Soo what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this adding gem 'figaro' to my gemfile.

Answer (score 0):

With my `secrets.yml` what I tend to do is:

```
# secrets.yml
local: &local
  secret_key_base: 123abc

remote: &remote
  secret_key_base: abc123
  aws_secret_key: <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY'] %>

development:
  <<: *local

test:
  <<: *local

production:
  <<: *remote
```

That above file should be a good enough proof of concept for what I tend to do. This way you can *store your secrets in your environment variables* and not have to commit them to source control. I never commit them to source control.

If a platform asks you to commit your secrets to source control, its a platform with some terrible software architecture. Architecture should always consider security.

Since you're on your development environment, you shouldn't actually need to connect to AWS S3, unless you're developing ontop of it. Ideally, to help speed up your development environment and to not clog up your servers, you can save the files into, say, your `public` folder and not on S3.